# Destroy game object immediately when new object is been called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using coroutine feature is working fine, but when I click the next button the new object should be created destroying the old object

```cs
public class SceneChanger: MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<string> sceneHistory = new List<string>();  //running history of scenes
    public GameObject[] charset; //The last string in the list is always the current scene running
    public GameObject changer;
    public int chartotalnum = 3;
    public float Timer;
    public int rand;
    public Button Next;
    public GameObject go;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Destroy(go, 5f);
        rand++;
        //StartCoroutine(Spawn());
        Button btn = Next.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(ClickedNext);
        //DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);  //Allow this object to persist between scene changes
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
      
    }
    
    IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        GameObject go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Debug.Log("test");
        rand++;
        Destroy(go, 5f);
    }
    
    public void ClickedNext()
    {
        StopCoroutine(Spawn());
        Destroy(go);
        go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        rand++;
        Destroy(go, 5f);
        
        Debug.Log("clicked");
        StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed using go, In the IEnumerator Spawn you try to use go = Instantiate.... isntead of GameObject go = Instantiate ...

Comment: i have tried it sir, the issue is the previous object doesnt gets destroyed when the new one is instantiated, when i remove the gameobject go from ienumerator the coroutine doesnt work

Comment: Make sure that you destroy in the spawn IEumerator as well Destroy(go); and just to not create an error i would check if go is null before destroying it.

Comment: IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Debug.Log("test");
        rand++;
        Destroy(go, 5f);
    }
    public void ClickedNext()
    {
        StopCoroutine(Spawn());
        Destroy(go);
        go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        rand++;
        Destroy(go, 5f);
        
        Debug.Log("clicked");
        StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }

Comment: From the code I guess this is what should happen ... just make sure you also only use `go = ...` in `Start` as well

Comment: thanks @derHugo, it works now i used go = in start too

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that in both `Start` and `Spawn` you use

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

and thereby create a local variable called `go` which hides your existing class field `go`.

It rather has to be

```
go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

in `Start` and `Spawn` in order to use the existing field instead a new local variable.

Answer (score -1):

i removed gameObject from
go = Instantiate(charset[rand], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;